# how to display view variable in a DisplayFor in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
            @{
            var name = Model.Rrole.Where(i => i.ROLEID == item.ROLEID);
            @Html.DisplayFor();
        }
```

i want display that name inside the DisplayFor but it through an error
this is my complete view

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like the following

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>name);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.name);` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a partial view for the type of Rrole, and place it either in the same views folder or one of the shared folders. And in that view display whatever you want.

```
 @{
            var name = Model.Rrole.Where(i => i.ROLEID == item.ROLEID);
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Rrole.Where(i => i.ROLEID == item.ROLEID).FirstOrDefault());
        }
```

If all you want to do is display the name of the role, then;

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Rrole.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ROLEID == item.ROLEID).Name);
```

Comment: after doing this it throughs an error                          "Value cannot be null."
"Parameter name: source"

Comment: then first make sure that Model.Rrole collection contains item.ROLEID. if (Model.RRole.Count(f => f.ROLEID == item.ROLEID)>0) {code to display}